# What is the best practice for storing an OAuth token in WinForms?

Tags: winforms, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2

I was wondering what the best practice is for storing an Authentication Token.

My usage scenario would be that the user could enable "Remember Authentication" and would be required to re-authenticate when the token expires. Otherwise it would just be for the "Session".

I was going to use a singleton class to do it and update a user setting if "Remember Authentication" is enabled, but I was wondering if that isn't secure or if there is a better way to do it.